# LayerToKML creates null vectors at 0,0

Tags: layer-to-kml

I'm writing a script in python that loops the LayerToKML conversion tool on a set of layers; the problem is that the first execution works fine, while the rest (hundreds) produce .kmz files like this...

[image]

...all the geometries are invisible and placed at the Equator or North Pole, while the attributes are correct.

I run the script with an IDE (PyScripter, 32 Bit, python 2.7.2): if I do it with the ArcGIS (10.1) python window, it works instead!

PS: athis is the code function that I use to convert the shapefiles:

```
def creatingKmz(fcKmz,fcName):

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcKmz, fcName)
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(fcName,inFolder + os.sep + fc + ".lyr")
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(fcName,outKMZDirectory + os.sep + fcName + ".kmz","1","false",arcpy.Describe(fcName).extent,"","","CLAMPED_TO_GROUND")
    arcpy.Delete_management(fcKmz)
```

Comment: do you mind posting your code?

Comment: Hy ZrSiO4, I've just added to the post the conversion function, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Hy everyone, we've solved the problem by changing the system decimal separator, from comma to point. Thanks for the attention and have a good day.